# Wordpress installation in subfolder backend not accessable

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a Wordpress installation in the root folder of my server and another Wordpress installation in a subfolder called "neueseite".

I can access the frontend of the page in the subfolder but not the admin area (backend). When I try to access it, it shows me a 404 error: https://paarkultur.ch/neueseite/wp-login.php

All URLs in the database contain the URL with the subfolder. I also tried different things with the .htaccess file. Nothing helped.

Here is the code inside the root directory's .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# Include in the next line all folders to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(neueseite) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And this is the code in the subfolders .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /neueseite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /neueseite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone help me figure out what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your nginx server and the below file is not located in the directory listed below:

> https://paarkultur.ch/neueseite/wp-login.php

I can see that you have various core files such as wp-config.php, readme.html, etc but you do not have wp-login.php in that directory.

Anyway if you are trying to serve multiple sites from a single server then you are going the wrong way about it

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. The file is there! See screenshot: [link](https://ibb.co/0nDBDBb)

Comment: I only want to have the website there for developing purposes. I will move it later to the root directory. But first I need to get it working in the subfolder.

Comment: Ok so like a staging site. For me I do the majority of staging locally, it much faster. I think one of the problems you are encountering is that you will need to set up a separate database for the second instance of wordpress

Comment: I did that too. It's a completely separate database.

Comment: Well considering your sever is returning a 404 response and you are saying that the wp-login.php file is located in that directory then it sounds like a server configuration issue. Your server is allowing access to wp-config.php, readme.html, etc but not to wp-login.php. Check server configuration files i.e. htaccess and  http.conf. Although I would expect a 403 response not a 404 response.